# SQLalchemy: pre-delete UPDATE not running when post_update=True

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an object model that uses an "action" system for tracking changes to an object. These actions can be added and are considered "proposed" until they're approved with an "approve" action. The full list of actions is reduced into "state" objects which are stored in the database as well, for quicker querying.

Because there are "proposed" actions, every object also has a second state object which tracks the "diff," which are basically the state changes for everything in the proposed (all other fields set to NULL). Finally, every state also tracks the last action, for display of the "last update" in the UI.

Here's my object:

```
class Subject(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'subjects'

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True)
    state_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('states.id', name="fk_state"))
    diff_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('states.id', name="fk_state_diff"))

    state = relationship('State', back_populates='subject', foreign_keys=[state_id], cascade='all, delete-orphan', lazy='joined', innerjoin=True, uselist=False, single_parent=True, post_update=True)
    diff = relationship('State', back_populates='subject', foreign_keys=[diff_id], cascade='all, delete-orphan', lazy='joined', innerjoin=True, uselist=False, single_parent=True, post_update=True)
    actions = relationship('Action', back_populates='subject', cascade='all, delete-orphan', order_by='Action.time', single_parent=True)
```

As you can see, it has a relationship to this Action object:

```
class Action(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'actions'

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True)
    subject_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('subjects.id'), nullable=False, index=True)

    time = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now(), nullable=False, index=True)
    # Other action properties here, omitted for brevity.
    # ...

    subject = relationship('Subject', back_populates='actions')
```

and both of those are related to the State object, with its proposed (many-to-many) and last_action properties.

```
proposed_action_data = Table(
    'proposed_actions',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('actions_id', UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('actions.id')),
    Column('state_id', UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('states.id'))
)

class State(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'states'

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True)
    last_action_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('actions.id', name="fk_state_last_action"), nullable=True)
    subject_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('subjects.id', name="fk_state_subject_id"), nullable=False)

    # State properties goes here, ommitted for brevity.
    # ...

    last_action = relationship('Action', lazy='joined', foreign_keys=[last_action_id], post_update=True)
    proposed = relationship('Action', secondary=proposed_action_data)
    subject = relationship('Subject', foreign_keys=[subject_id)
```

Inserts seem to be working just fine - I can set the state and diff, and an `UPDATE` statement is issued for the Subject after the State's `INSERT` statement, so the IDs are set.

But if I want to delete a Subject the pre-delete `UPDATE` statement to clear the state_id and diff_id isn't run, so it tries to delete the State and fails, since it's still referenced:

```
session.delete(subject)
session.commit()
```

raises:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) update or delete on table "states" violates foreign key constraint "fk_state_diff" on table "subjects"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(363eb5bb-4042-44a9-b3fe-567406008f9e) is still referenced from table "subjects".
[SQL: 'DELETE FROM states WHERE states.id = %(id)s'] [parameters: ({'id': UUID('363eb5bb-4042-44a9-b3fe-567406008f9e')}, {'id': UUID('b7ca4f02-0fac-41bf-ae8b-44049ceb1855')})]
```

If I clear the state and diff manually, I get no exceptions:

```
subject.state = None
subject.diff = None
session.delete(subject)
session.commit()
```

What am I doing wrong here?